# Is there a way to install Flask globally

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am new to Python. Today I installed flask in C:Users\myName\FolderA using below commands and it worked fine. But when i try to create a structure C:Users\myName\FolderA\FolderB and create app.py in it, my VSCode says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'". Does this mean i need to install flask in Folder B too? Is there a way to install flask globally and make all folders under 'FolderA' access the libs?

Commands used to install Flask

- C:Users\myName\FolderA\py -m venv env
- C:Users\myName\FolderA\env\Scripts\activate
- (env)c:Users\myName\FolderA\pip install flask

Comment: No you don't need to install flask every time, may be you forgot to activate the virtual environment in another terminal

Answer (score 0):

You are using a virtualenv. Everything installed inside a virtualenv resides inside that virtualenv (which is nice in fact: all your dependencies for that project only!).

If you want to install packages globally, run

```
pip install flask
```

**without** having run the **activate** script first (that **activates** your virtualenv).

Answer (score -1):

PIP should install packages globally. You shouldn't have to reinstall flask everytime. Seems like something is wrong with your PIP. How did you install Python?

You could try updating PIP, which could fix it. Try running

```
python -m pip install –upgrade pip
```

in cmd.

**Edit:** This could also be an issue with Visual Studio Code. Try running the python code through CMD.